# Duplicate Training Data in Decision Tree Learning Algortihm

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, cart

I have the following training data set where the first line shows the name of attributes.

```
S_Length, Se_Width, P_Length, P_Width, Predicate
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Ili
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iri
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iyr
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Ir
5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,Po
5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,II
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Ir
5.0,3.4,1.5,0.2,Imt
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Ir
```

In the above data set, in row 4,7, and 9, the data sets are duplicate, How does it affect the algorithm? Is there a difference when we use large data set or small data set with duplicate values?

Answer (score 4):

You tree will give more "importance" to the datapoints that are duplicated because the loss function will double count the error from those datapoints.

If *every* single datapoint was duplicated, then the resulting decision tree would not be any different. What is important is the ratio of duplicated datapoints to the number of non-duplicated dataponts, not the size of the dataset itself. (Except if you consider running time...)

Sometimes "duplicate" datapoints are legitimate, and those should not be thrown away.

Comment: However, i feel that, wont having a duplicate value create a change in
weight? For instance:

5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa

2,3,4,5 are the same training sets, and wouldn't this affect the size
of nodes as the tree is being built. When you have duplicated records,
then you are implicitly putting a weight on the values in those rows.

Comment: Yes that's right. Duplicating a datapoint will give that datapoint double the weight, and will therefore affect the resulting decision tree.

Whether you want to throw out duplicates or not depends on goals/context. If those duplicates arise naturally, and you're interested in maximizing the number of correctly predicted categories, then you shouldn't throw them away. They give you information about the relative occurrences of datapoints.

Comment: As a heads up, this is not unique to decision trees. It really depends on your loss function - e.g. any loss function that sums (or something) across all the points will give duplicated data points more importance.